Determining if a field extension of a function field is a splitting field
Here is a textbook question from a textbook: Abstract Algebra: A Comprehensive Introduction by John W. Lawrence and Frank A. Zorzitto. I am trying to solve this question in preparation for my final exam.
Let $\mathbb{Z}_3(t)$ be the field of rational functions in the variable $t$ and having coefficients in the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_3$. If $\alpha$ is a root of $X^3 - t$, is the field extension $\mathbb{Z}_3(t)[\alpha]$ a splitting field over $\mathbb{Z}_3(t)$?
Here is my work so far.
We need to check if $X^3-t$ splits over $\mathbb{Z}_3(t)[\alpha]$. Since $\alpha$ is a solution then we can set $\alpha = t^{1/3}$ to be a function with input $t$. Then by polynomial long divison and applying the quadratic formula, we get that $-t^{1/3}=-\alpha$ account for the two solutions of the remaining quadratic. Thus the given field extension is a splitting field for the given polynomial.
I would just like some confirmation if the substitution for $\alpha = t^{1/3}$ is valid and where in the text I can determine this to be true. I read the section on function fields, but I am unsure in how it applies. My thinking so far is that our given function field is a subset of the complex function field.

You are making far too heavy weather of this. The first sentence of your work is correct. The second should be "Clearly this is so since $(X-\alpha)^3=X^3-\alpha^3=X^3-t$". That's all.

The only way we can characterize the solution of $X^3-t$ is "it is a zero of the polynomial $X^3-t$ in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Z_3(t)$".
(Yes I admit this is abstract).
However $\mathbb Z_3(\alpha)$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $X^3-t$ over $\mathbb Z_3(t)$.
The proof is by noting that $\alpha$ is the unique zero of $X^3-t$ (and therefore its multiplicity is $3$):
$$(X-\alpha)^3=X^3-3X^2\alpha+3\alpha^2X-\alpha^3=X^3-t,  $$
where we used $\alpha^3=t$ and the field has characteristic $3$ (hence the two middle term vanishes).

So when are we allowed to declare that $\alpha$ is an algebraic function? Here is an excerpt from the section on function fields.

Take $F = \mathbb{C}(t)$, the field of rational functions in the indeterminate $t$ with coefficients in the complex numbers. By Eisenstein’s criterion, Proposition 5.40, using the prime $t$ in the unique factorization domain $\mathbb{C}[t]$, the polynomial $X^4 - t$ is irreducible in $F[X]$. By Kronecker’s theorem, there is a field $K$ containing a root $\alpha$ of $X^4 - t$. This root satisfies the equation $\alpha^4 = t$ inside $K$.

The indeterminate $t$ can be interpreted as the identity function $z \mapsto z$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Thus, we may view $\alpha$ as a function defined on a suitable region of $\mathbb{C}$ whose fourth power gives the identity function. In other words, we can think of $\alpha$ as the function $z \mapsto z^{1/4}$ defined on a suitable region of $\mathbb{C}$. Algebraic elements over $\mathbb{C}(t)$, such as our $\alpha$, are known as algebraic functions.

Alright, I will try and digest this information

Sorry, please ignore the comment I deleted. I think that one can define an algebra function $t^{\frac 13}$ on $\mathbb Z_3$, but it might not help the problem. (I was proving such $\alpha$ is not rational function, and then realized here we are talking about algebraic functions.)

So can I define an algebraic function the way I did?

In this case you can because such an function exists (the identity function on $\mathbb Z_3$ $f(x)=x$ is a function satisfying $f^3(x)-x=0,\forall x\in\mathbb Z_3$) and is unique. But in general the existence is not guaranteed. For instance no function $g:\mathbb Z_3\to\mathbb Z_3$ satisfies $g^2(x)-2=0,\forall x\in\mathbb Z_3$ (i.e. solves $X^2-2=0$ where $2$ is viewed as a constant function. It depends on the specific polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb Z_3(t)[X]$. Also when the polynomial admits solution, it might not be unique.
